# Tukey (bisquare) Psi on GLM Poisson robust model

Tags: r, glm

when using library("robust base"), how to force the model to use the Turkey psi function? I tried to add method="MT" but it doesn't work.
Thanks.

```
modelRob<-glmrob(x ~ as.factor(i) + as.factor(j),family = poisson(link = "log"), data = mydata)
```

Comment: from the vignette "method="MT", currently only implemented for family = poisson, computes an “[M]-Estimator
based on [T]ransformation”, by Valdora and Yohai (2013)" you could use `MASS::rlm(..., psi = psi.bisquare)`

Comment: Nathan Day I tried a several ways with `MASS::rlm(..., psi = psi.bisquare)`, how can I used as a glm with family = poisson(link = "log")  ?? Thanlyou

Comment: would it be feasible to use `rlm(log(x) ~...)`